# Can't run python command

Tags: python

I wanted to run python on my mac, but I get `zsh: command not found: python`

Python3 is installed. I googled it. People usually solve this issue by running this command `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

Bu in my case, I get `ln: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted`

How can I get this working? Thanks!

Comment: possible cross site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591971/how-to-fix-zsh-command-not-found-python-error-macos-monterey-12-3-python

Comment: [Edit] your question and include your `$HOME/.bash_profile` for us.

Comment: try `sudo` in front of your command.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run this in your zsh terminal:
`echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc`

It will force zsh to point to the python version you are trying to point to, even using the `python` command in your terminal.

You could also run `which python3` to find the absolute path to your python 3 executable.